# Bulk URL to google shorten URL dynamically

Tags: php, api

Is it possible to convert bulk URL to google shorten URL at a single sort with out using for loop in Google API?

I have only single url shorten code

```
require_once('GoogleApi.php');
$GoogleApi = new GoogleUrlApi('APIKEY');    
$shorten_url = $GoogleApi->shorten($pageUrl);
$expand_url = $GoogleApi->expand($shorten_url);
```

Comment: Show your code here

Comment: I have only single url shorten 


       `require_once('GoogleApi.php');
 $GoogleApi = new GoogleUrlApi('APIKEY'); 
 $shorten_url = $GoogleApi->shorten($pageUrl);
 $expand_url = $GoogleApi->expand($shorten_url);`